# Cannot created a new mvc 5 controller when using a reference from other solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am facing a strange problem, probably its something simple...

When i create a controller using entity framework option, the entity for example 'Product' will be not visible in the list of 'Model Class'.
This happens only if the object 'Product' is located in other solution.(reference from other solution to my website project).

when i am using a domain model in the same solution or in the same project of the web site => the object is visible for selection in the 'Model Class'

this happens with visual studio 2013, mvc5 and entity framework 6.1.1
Using code first and c#.

any advice would be appreciated

thank you

Ori

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Temporarily add the project that has 'Product' class to this solution.
- Build solution.
- Now you should be able to create controller using scaffolding.
- After that can remove the project from solution. (and add its dll reference if required)

Comment: I have done this already and it works. it was surprising to find out that there are difference between the reference i have added to the project. doesn't make sense...